# emacs flymake mode fails for coffeescript

Tags: emacs, coffeescript, flymake

I am trying to run flymake mode with CoffeeScript. For some reason when I invoke flymake mode I get this message (Its all on one line in the error log):

> Flymake: Configuration error has occurred while running
>   (/usr/bin/coffee /tmp/flymake16162knP.coffee). Flymake will be
>   switched OFF

I had thought that it could not find the coffeescript command so I gave it the full path but as of now I can't get it to work.

Comment: Are you using my `flymake-coffee.el` (https://github.com/purcell/flymake-coffee)? If so, I'll arrange to incorporate the fix from @syohex.

Comment: This is now fixed upstream in version 0.6 of flymake-coffee.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You add following S-exp to your configuration file(maybe coffee-mode hook function).

```
(defadvice flymake-post-syntax-check (before flymake-force-check-was-interrupted)
    (setq flymake-check-was-interrupted t))
(ad-activate 'flymake-post-syntax-check)
```

flymake throws exception when exit status is non-zero and compile process was not
interrupted. This S-exp forces to assign flymake-check-was-interrupted to true,
and avoids flymake exception.